# how to do slash substitution in shell in one line?

Tags: bash, shell, github-actions, sh

If I run this command in a shell terminal

```
A="feature/test-slash"
echo ${A//\//-}
```

it returns `feature-test-slash`

But if I run

```
echo ${feature/test-slash//\//-}
```

it returns an empty string.

How can I do it in one line?

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76759170/how-to-replace-slashes-in-github-action-expression)

Comment: `${}` is for variables. If you have a string literal, not inside a variable, why not just write it correctly yourself?

Comment: @Verpous see the related question and you will understand my motivation. what is your alternative solution?

Comment: What's wrong with the proposed solutions in the related question?

Comment: @tjm3772 read the update section. it is not working

Comment: So you're asking how to do parameter expansion without a variable? Why do you need that?

Comment: @AminBa If the string you want to process is the output of a command, not a value of a bash variable, please edit your question and explain that. We don't even need the command. Name it `foobar` if you wish. Or replace it with `printf 'feature/test-slash\n'`. But do not ask how to do substitutions in a variable if there is no variable. Example of answer you could get with the proper question: pipe your command to `sed 's!/!-!g'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "feature/test-slash" | tr '/' '-'
```

Your solution doesn't work because ${} is intended for use with variables.

Answer (score 0):

> how to do slash substitution in shell in one line?

Join lines with `;`.

```
A="feature/test-slash"; echo ${A//\//-}
```